# Platform-dependent data output

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio, overloading, rstudio-server

In order to aid myself with displaying debugging information, I decided to create the following tiny function that would **dynamically** switch between displaying data in RStudio's internal data browser and simple character-based output, depending on *capabilities* of the platform, where my modules are being sourced at:

```
View <- function (...) {
  if (.Platform$GUI == "RStudio")
    View(...)
  else
    print(...)
}
```

This function is located, along with other utility functions, in the module `<PROJ_HOME>/utils/debug.R`. All modules that need these functions, include it via `source("../utils/debug.R")`.

Running my project's code on my Amazon EC2 instance's Linux console is fine. However, running it on the same virtual machine via RStudio Server results in the following error message:

```
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

It seems to me that R gets confused as to which `View()` function needs to be called. Initially, I assumed that RStudio **overloads** the `utils::View()` and I tried to call it explicitly, but it failed. Then I thought that RStudio somehow defines its `View()` implementation in global environment, so that it just needs to be called `View()` without package/library reference. However, as I you see, it doesn't work either. Another potential reason of the error might be that I overestimated the "smartness" of R in terms of my use of `...` arguments.

So, what is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: How about an explicit utils::View(...) call in your function ?

Comment: @KarlForner: Just discovered your comment. I've tried `utils::View(...)` call, but it results in the following error and warning: `"Error in .External2(C_dataviewer, x, title) : invalid device
In addition: Warning message:
In utils::View(...) : unable to open display"`. That's running my code in RStudio Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RStudio hooks the `View` function. One approach might be to see if anyone has overridden the View function from utils, and to call the override if it exists. What about this?

```
View <- if (identical(utils::View, View)) print else View
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, Jonathan! However, your approach results in the same error and warning as mentioned in my comment to Karl above.

Comment: Jonathan, please disregard my previous comment - I realized that I was testing your changes without clearing R environment (workspace). When I tested your code after properly clearing the workspace, it works well on both platforms exactly as I planned. Great job! Thank you again! Answer accepted! So, from your answer I conclude that R allows overriding functions with omitting (...) arguments syntax. Correct? I would appreciate if you'd take a look at my recent R questions at: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2872891/aleksandr-blekh?tab=questions&sort=newest.

Comment: I'm still curious about why my original approach produces a recursion error, while your (essentially very similar) code doesn't...

Comment: Your original approach creates a function that calls `View`. R resolves function names at the moment the function runs.

Comment: The modified approach works because it copies functions rather than wrapping them. The copy happens before the assignment of `View`, so inside the assignment `View` refers to its earlier definition.

Comment: One of R's more confusing features is the ability to have several different variables with the same name all present in different environments--to understand what function/variable is being referred to at runtime, it's useful to look at environment bindings if you haven't already: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html

Comment: Appreciate your clear explanation! I knew a bit about R environments, but not in the context of functions. Learning something new about R every day...